# $\Bbb{R}^3 \backslash \Bbb{R}^2$ is disconnected. Show that $\Bbb{R}^4 \backslash \Bbb{R}^2$ is path connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

So far, I understand that we need to show that you can form a path, but I am very confused on how to go about it. Can anyone provide hints please?

Comment: I suppose these are set differences, e.g., $\Bbb R^3 - \Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Since $R^4\setminus R^2$ is $R^2\setminus R^0 \times R^2$, it suffices to prove that $R^2$ minus a point is path connected.

Comment: @Stefan: parentheses would help there! I assume you mean $(\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb R^0) \times \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @TonyK: Exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see that $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus(\mathbb{R}^2\times\{0\})$ is disconnected, you could use the open sets $\{(x,y,z):z>0\}$ and $\{(x,y,z):z<0\}$.

To see that $\mathbb{R}^4\setminus(\mathbb{R}^2\times\{(0,0)\})$ is connected, you can use paths between elements.  To connect $(a,b,c,d)$ with $(e,f,g,h)$, you can construct a path from $(a,b,c,d)$ to $(a,b,1,1)$ and similarly a path between $(e,f,g,h)$ and $(e,f,1,1)$.  Then, you can construct a path between $(a,b,1,1)$ and $(e,f,1,1)$ all while avoiding $\mathbb{R}^2\times\{(0,0)\}$.  More precisely:

- If $c=0$, then observe that $d\not=0$ because otherwise the starting point is in $\mathbb{R}^2\times\{(0,0)\}$.  Now, consider the path given by $(a,b,t,d)$ for $t\in[0,1]$.  When $t=0$, you have $(a,b,c,d)=(a,b,0,d)$ and when $t=1$, you have $(a,b,1,d)$.  This can be followed by the path $(a,b,1,(1-s)d+s)$ for $s\in[0,1]$.  When $s=0$, you have $(a,b,1,d)$ and when $s=1$, you have $(a,b,1,1)$.  You can observe that throughout this process, the third and fourth positions are never both zero.
- If $c\not=0$, then consider the path given by $(a,b,c,(1-t)d+t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ which is $(a,b,c,d)$ for $t=0$ and $(a,b,c,1)$ for $t=1$.  Then, consider the path $(a,b,(1-s)c+s,1)$ for $s\in[0,1]$.  When $s=0$, the point is $(a,b,c,1)$ and when $s=1$, the points is $(a,b,1,1)$.  You can observe that throughout this process, the third and fourth positions are never both zero.
- The path between $(a,b,1,1)$ and $(e,f,1,1)$ can be formed by $((1-t)a+te,(1-t)b+tf,1,1)$ for $t\in[0,1]$.